# Question with installing backup camera

Tags: backup-camera

Hey yall im trying to install the backup camera that came with my GPS unit from amazon. The only issue is that there is no ground wire with the backup camera wires. The backup camera has the av male (which plugs into the screen unit) and splitting off just one red wire (which I am going to wire to the reverse light for power). My question is, will it be an issue that there is no ground wire too? Is there something I should do differently?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Motor vehicles typically use the chassis as earth/ground. You may find that internally, the camera has a wire running to a mounting bracket, with the expectations that the bracket is going to be attached to a body ground in some manner.